# Microcontroller Newbe here. LED color pattern controller for arcade machine

Tags: microcontroller, led

I am building an arcade machine and I want to make a cool led light display for the marquee.

You can see pictures of what I'm talking about here.

https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/1230061_570411899671967_1321087113_n.jpg

https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/1233534_570411943005296_504722957_n.jpg

I want to light up each one of those holes with an LED, and make it so I can program the LED's to create different effects.

I have no experience with micro controllers, but I do have some programing experience (PHP, javaScript) and good soldering skills.

I don't have a clue where to start though. I'm looking for some advice and guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: arduino is a good choice for banging something like this out.  If you want to use something other than C then maybe a raspberry pi or beaglebone either running linux.  sparkfun.com is a good site whatever path you take.

Comment: I actually prefer things like the msp430 launchpad or the stellaris launchpad which is now renamed to something else, but both are from ti.com.  you definitely would want C with a little assembly for those which it didnt sound like you have.  Also there is the stm32f0 discover or the stm32f4 discovery from st, good choices, but also there is that C plus maybe asm programming requirement.  The microcontroller likely wont drive all the lights you want so you may have to boost that which takes electronics skill or some googling or just use an arduino shield...

Comment: so for a quick and dirty just do it one of the arduino family may work, geez even the lilypad may work for you, dont have to sew it onto clothes but there are a number of little led boards and other items that with some diffusion overyour holes a super bright led might just do the trick.